# Tor change identity command

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration

USE:
- Tor expert bundle
- Windows 7 64bit

I have a start Tor.exe and works...
But do not know how to change identity (Generate new IP already running process Tor.exe)

Answer (score 0):

Tor Portable:
https://mega.nz/#!FVsVhJKC!Y3L6J7ALqRwPhD5bODe3m5vfbUMbOXMGzXnM5MyWyc4

Video (IP address does not change):
https://mega.nz/#!5N8HhCqD!h2hcrq_7338KsuQXPtHvoorezIL80bOHv3K71Ir12Vo

Thx Help me...

PS: who deleted posts?

Comment: Deeply uneasy with you distributing binary code from some random internet link...

Comment: If you don't believe me you can replace binaries https://www.torproject.org/dist/torbrowser/6.5/tor-win32-0.2.9.9.zip OR Test files using a hash.

Comment: That's entirely irrelevant, the links may be okay today but what about tomorrow? It's simply not something users should be recommended to do or let them get into the habit of doing.

Comment: No one forces you to run binaries. I do not want here to start the conversation off topic his opinion I told you...

Answer (score 0):

You "Tor portable" seems to be a malware: tor *is* portable by it's nature, especially under windows: just put a folder *wherever you wish* and that's it. And also keep in mind - IP change speed depends on your connection, it's not an instant switching: give it 5-10 seconds at least.